# Gnuplot pull function range from a file for each row

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to display a function which is a linear function f(x)=a*x+b with different coefficients in each range. My file (output.txt) looks like this but without the header:

```
a          b        range
-0.0645991 0.439102 0    0.25
-0.230142  0.480488 0.25 0.5
-0.438559  0.584697 0.5  0.75
-0.66962   0.757993 0.75 1
-0.898603  0.986975 1    1.25
-1.09846   1.2368   1.25 1.5
-1.24232   1.45259  1.5  1.75
-1.30601   1.56404  1.75 2
```

I have tried these lines but none of them worked:

`plot "output.txt" using 1:2 with lines, set xrange using 3:4`

`plot "output.txt" [($3):($4)] ($1)*x+($2)`

`plot "output.txt" $3<=x<=$4 ? ($1)*x+($2) : 0`

It's my first time using Gnuplot and I couldn't find any example of pulling range from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You can simply use the plotting style `with vectors`.
Check `help vectors`.
The plotting command looks complicated but it is straightforward.
The four values you need are:  `x`, `y`, `delta x`, and `delta y`, i.e.
in your example

- `x`: 3rd column
- `y`: `f(x,a,b)` where `x` is 3rd column and `a` and `b` are from 1st and 2nd columns, respectively.
- `dx`: 4th column less 3rd column
- `dy`: `f(x,a,b)` where `x` is from 4th column less `f(x,a,b)` where `x` is from 3rd column and `a,b` as above.

You can skip the arrow heads if you specify `nohead` in the plot command. Check `help arrow`.

**Code:**

```
### plotting style with vectors
reset session

$Data <<EOD
a          b        range
-0.0645991 0.439102 0    0.25
-0.230142  0.480488 0.25 0.5
-0.438559  0.584697 0.5  0.75
-0.66962   0.757993 0.75 1
-0.898603  0.986975 1    1.25
-1.09846   1.2368   1.25 1.5
-1.24232   1.45259  1.5  1.75
-1.30601   1.56404  1.75 2
EOD

f(x,a,b) = a*x + b

plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors lc "red" head title "my function"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The command works. I still can't make the "nohead" work though. I've tried `set arrow nohead` and just `nohead` in the plot command.

Comment: I managed to make it work with `plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors nohead` which is enough for me, however when i add `lc "red" head title "my function"` or just `head title "my function"` at the end it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Is there some sort of separator necessary?

Comment: @Tortoise  is it fully solved now? Which version of gnuplot are you running? What does "doesn't work" mean? Any error messages? The above code should run as is for gnuplot >=5.0 and with some adaptions also with earlier versions.

Comment: `plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors nohead lc "red"` works fine but when I try `plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors nohead lc "red" head title "my function"` or `plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors nohead head title "my function"` it points at "head" and says: "duplicated arguments in style specification". I don't need the title so it is fully solved, but I was wondering why such combination doesn't work. The gnuplot version is 5.4.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm so silly. `plot $Data u 3:(f($3,$1,$2)):($4-$3):(f($4,$1,$2)-f($3,$1,$2)) w vectors nohead lc "red" title "my function"` works. I added unnecessary "head" after using "nohead". Sorry for wasting your time for no reason. Everything is good now.